# I can't bind a datagrid using the entity framework

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, binding, datagrid

I'm trying to bind a datagrid in two ways using THE entity framework on WPF. I can't add anything using my datagrid 
after pressing save all the data will disappeared and it won't save on the database

```
<Grid>
    <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" x:Name="Datag" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="180,24,0,0"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="200" Width="551">         
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn   Width="100" Binding="{Binding id, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn  Width="100" Binding="{Binding names, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn  Width="100" Binding="{Binding number, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>      
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

This is my code:

```
testsEntities db = new testsEntities();

 public MainWindow()
 {
     InitializeComponent();
     Datag.ItemsSource = db.Test_table.ToList();         
 }

 private void save(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
     Datag.Items.Refresh();
     db.SaveChanges();
 }
```

Comment: if you do `.ToList()` I'm not sure if it will still update it. Will it work without (idk as I'm not familiair with WPF and EF)?

Comment: Also what do you mean by `it won't be saved on the data` does that mean its not in the database after you add it?

Comment: when i use Datag.ItemsSource = db.Test_table.ToList(); again or rerun the app I won't find the data I added

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that comment. Does it save to the database currently and just not display it or does it not display AND not save to the database?

Comment: if I used a form to add the data to the grid and my database then it will be saved but when I use datagrid it won't save

Comment: Ah, in that case maybe `.ToList()` is the issue. I'm not sure. But include that information in your question (that it won't save in DB either) because the current answer thinks it goes in the db too. - edit - There goes the answer, that's why you need to specify everything :)

Comment: When I don't use toList()......
Data binding directly to a store query (DbSet, DbQuery, DbSqlQuery) is not supported. Instead populate a DbSet with data, for example by calling Load on the DbSet, and then bind to local data. For WPF bind to DbSet.Local. For WinForms bind to DbSet.Local.ToBindingList().

Comment: Idk what you mean and can't help you further. Your question is quite unclear. If you want help (from other people because I'm just guessing) you need to specify what you want to happen and what happens now. (By editing the question, not by commenting)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, last edit.

it seems that you are almost in the right way, it is using binding (`Binding id, ...`) in the datagrid, but it does not seem to be using a viewmodel (your save is an event in code behind `save(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)` )

I'll get your data directly from your datagrid, if it's not null, I'll treat it and write it using Entity Framework

```
private void save(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {

        using (var db = new testsEntities())
        {
            if (Datag.ItemsSource == null) 
                return; //Or throw
            var listOfItems = (IEnumerable<Test_table>)Datag.ItemsSource;
            foreach(var item in listOfItems)
            {
                var model = db.Test_table.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Id == item.Id)
                if (model?.Id > 0)
                {
                    model.names = item.names;
                    model.number = item.number;
                    db.Entry(model).State = EntityState.Modified;
                }
                else
                    db.Test_table.Add(item);

                db.SaveChanges();
            }

        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
         //Do Something
    }
}
```